# Calling Partial View from different projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Within the project I'm using this code `@Html.Partial("../ReferenceChangeLog/ReferenceChangeLogPopUp")` for calling the controller and action.

Here ReferenceChangeLog is Controller Name. `ReferenceChangeLogPopUp(ReferenceChangeLogPopUp.cshtml)` is Partial View Name.

How can I set the path for calling another project's controller and action ?

Answer (score 3):

That's not supported out of the box. By default Razor views are only resolved within the current project which is what you deploy as an ASP.NET application in IIS. If you need to implement this, you will have to write a custom Razor view engine capable of retrieving views from arbitrary locations on the file system. Here's, for example, [an article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) which explains how you could embed Razor views into assemblies and reuse them across multiple projects.