# Looking in wrong project for view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Nevermind, typical absent-mindedness... I had the RazorGenerator nuget package installed but NOT the RazorGenerator extension... I'm just gonna back away slowly...

I am currently working on creating a centralized login system that can be shared across a multitude of MVC web apps.

Right now, I have a model, a controller, and a view, all in the shared project. I can ActionLink from another view in the main project to the controller in the shared project just fine. However, even though the controller, model, and view in question are in the shared project, the app is looking in the main project's ~\Views folder. (I verified this by copy/pasting the view into the main project's directory to see if it would work... and it did)

There doesn't seem to be anything in the code influencing where the app looks for the view, so why is it looking in a different project's directory?

I didn't see any existing topics about this issue, but this is kind of an awkward issue to Google, so I apologize if this question was asked already.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [Calling Partial View from different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664505/calling-partial-view-from-different-projects)

If you're in a shared project trying to invoke a share project's view you might have to give explicit path to the view in question (relative to `~\` of main project).

Another option is to use `Areas`. More information in the links below.

[MSDN: Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Using areas in ASP.NET MVC to organize a project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/601504/Using-areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC-to-organize-a-project)

Comment: I have this working already with other views in the same project (I actually used that same article you linked), so I'd rather not overhaul the whole thing to use areas.

Comment: Oh and also, it's not that I want to call the view from a different project, the view is in the same project as the controller, but the app is, for some reason, looking in a different project.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant as well. When you call a view in the same project its path should still be relative to the main project. Same as when you have web.config for each project and when you try to read properties from it - you'll only be reading properties from the main project's web.config, no matter what project you're calling it from. I think a similar concept applies here.

Comment: Alright, this is pretty funny... I had the RazorGenerator nuget package installed but NOT the RazorGenerator extension... d'oh! Thanks for your answer, though!